# Why is AdminClient not failing when creating a topic with Kafka cluster not running?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Why don't I get an error message when I run the following producer code and Kafka is not even running?

I would expect the `createTopics` method to throw an exception, but it doesn't happen. Why?

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "1000");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);
NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic("events", 1, (short) 1);
adminClient.createTopics(Arrays.asList(newTopic));
adminClient.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [createTopics](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createTopics-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsOptions-) returns a `CreateTopicsResult` with `KafkaFutures` as values. As you are currently not blocking your code for this action to be finished (using `get`) and not catching any Exception, your code will just run fine without any notification that the broker is not available.

The following code will throw an `ExecutionException` when your broker is not available:

```java
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "5000");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);
NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic("events-test", 1, (short) 1);
CreateTopicsResult topicResult = adminClient.createTopics(Arrays.asList(newTopic));
KafkaFuture<Void> resultFuture = topicResult.all();
try {
    resultFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
adminClient.close();
```

I tested it using Kafka client 2.5.0 and here is the Excpetion:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1601136227182) timed out at 1601136227183 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at org.michael.big.data.kafka.java.BasicAdminClient.main(BasicAdminClient.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1601136227182) timed out at 1601136227183 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Be aware that the class `Admin` (the super class of `AdminClient`) is annotated as *Evolving* and might be changed in future releases.